# pd.Series of Lists - Check for Element in Lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame in which one column has lists as entries. For a given given value `x` I want to get a pd.Series of booleans telling me whether `x` is in each list. For example, given the DataFrame

```
    index    lists
    0        []
    1        [1, 2]
    2        [1]
    3        [3, 4]
```

I want to do something like `df.lists.contains(1)` and get back `False, True, True, False`.

I am aware I can do this with a Python loop or comprehension, but I would ideally like a Pandas solution analogous to `df.mod`, `df.isin` etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
In [79]: df['lists'].apply(lambda c: 1 in c)
Out[79]:
0    False
1     True
2     True
3    False
Name: lists, dtype: bool
```

PS I think a list comprehension solution might be faster in this case

Timing for 40.000 rows DF:

```
In [81]: df = pd.concat([df] * 10**4, ignore_index=True)

In [82]: df.shape
Out[82]: (40000, 2)

In [83]: %timeit df['lists'].apply(lambda c: 1 in c)
22.5 ms ± 87.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In [84]: %timeit [1 in x for x in df['lists']]
4.87 ms ± 25.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Oh! I forgot about `apply` somehow -- how stupid of me! Why would the list comprehension be faster?

Comment: @Alex, `apply` is bit  optimized `for ... loop` under the hood, so often list comprehension is faster compared to `DataFrame.apply(...)`